# How to prove this equality of double q-series?

Tags: power-series, special-functions

It is well-known that the $q$-Pochhammer symbol has the series expansion
$$
\frac{1}{(z;q)} = \sum_{\mathfrak{m} = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{z^m}{(q;q)_\mathfrak{m}} \ .
$$

Recently I encountered a double expansion resembling the above,
$$
\begin{align}
  & \ \frac{z^{-1}}{(q_1q_2)^{1/2} - (q_1q_2)^{ - 1/2}} + \sum_{\mathfrak{m}_1, \mathfrak{m}_2 = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{z^{\mathfrak{m}_1 + \mathfrak{m}_2}}{(q_1;q_1)_{\mathfrak{m}_1}(q_2;q_2)_{\mathfrak{m}_2}} R(\mathfrak{m}_1, \mathfrak{m}_2) \\
= & \  \frac{1}{(q_1q_2)^{1/2} - (q_1q_2)^{ -1/2}} \frac{1 - z}{z} \frac{1}{(z;q_1)(z;q_2)} \ ,
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
R(\mathfrak{m}_1, \mathfrak{m}_2) = \frac{1}{q_1^{\frac{\mathfrak{m}_1}{2}}q_2^{ - \frac{\mathfrak{m}_2 + 1}{2}} - q_1^{ - \frac{\mathfrak{m}_1}{2}}q_2^{ \frac{\mathfrak{m}_2 + 1}{2}}}\cdot
\frac{1}{q_1^{\frac{\mathfrak{m}_1 + 1}{2}}q_2^{ - \frac{\mathfrak{m}_2}{2}} - q_1^{ - \frac{\mathfrak{m}_1 + 1}{2}}q_2^{ \frac{\mathfrak{m}_2}{2}}} \ .
$$

I wonder how to prove this? Is it discussed in the literature?